# Automatic hiding blank rows after change

Tags: excel, hide, rows, vba

In my worksheet(book1) that vlookup data from another sheet(book2), I need to hide automatically all blank rows (even if they contain formula) and unhide them if the value changed automatically.
mean if I change the values in the book 2 sheet the book 1 sheet should react automatically by hiding or unhiding rows.

Here is the code.

```
Sub hideEmptyRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 117
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then 
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If 
    Next i Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Hi Mr Mush, I found this code to hide blank rows but it not what I'm looking for. Sub hideEmptyRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 117
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Comment: Does it output `0`? Does it output `#N/A`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub hideEmptyRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Hidden = False 'unhide all
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'find the last row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = "" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = 0 Or IsError(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then 'if it's an empty string, a 0 (empty cell) or an error
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'then hide it
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    UpBound = Cells.Rows.Count 'hides all rows after the last used one
    Range(LastRow + 1 & ":" & UpBound).Rows.Hidden = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: thank u so much user3819867, the code does hide successfully the blank rows, but i still need it to be updated automatically - if I make a row blank it should be disappear without running the macro each time. cloud please assist me on this?

Comment: There are various sources on how to link a [macro to an event](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx). You need to add the `Worksheet_Change` event trigger to either the worksheet's module or the workbook's.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that, I'm not well familiar with VBA

Comment: Good News user3819867, I succeed to hide the blank rows automatically after change :) one more thing please, the hided rows contain formula, if the value changed (the formula bring data via VLOOKUP from other sheet B so if I changed the sheet B the related hided row will no more be blank and should appear again this is what I need) could you please assist me have it back to and unhide it after change also if the value change !!

Comment: Hi again @user3819867, I found this code that hide blank rows and unhide non blank rows exactly as I want it, but it's a little bit slow. could please enhance it and make run after each change? CODE : Sub HideRows()
    Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
    Dim strVal As String
     
    Set rRange = Worksheets(7).Range("A1:A100")
     
    For Each rCell In rRange
       strVal = rCell & rCell(1, 2)
       rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = strVal = vbNullString
    Next rCell
     
     'A, B, C & D are empty.
    
End Sub